# Using PHP & MySQL to populate dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a second dropdown list using the value selected from a first dropdown list using **PHP** and **MySQL**, and without refreshing the page. I thought this would be simple but can't get it to work so any help would be much appreciated.

So far, I have the following:

**HTML Form (form.php)**

```
<select name="list1" id="list1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="list2" id="list2">

</select>
```

**JavaScript (within form.php)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#list1").change(function() {
    $("#list2").load("get_list2.php?id=" + $("#list1").val());
  });
</script>
```

**get_list2.php**

```
require_once("config.php");

$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)){
  echo "<option>".$row1['item']."</option>";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Try calling get_list2.php on it's own with an id and see what's returned.

Comment: Your code seems vulnerable for SQL injections. Don't use `$_GET` directly in a statemenet like this. Check out [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: If you want to update the second list without refreshing the page you should look into AJAX. If the complete list isn't too long you could also load all elements togehter with the first list and change the displayed items using Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @insertusernamehere - Does the move from MySQL mean that my code will just one day stop working?

Comment: It's not exactly a move away from MySQL. Only the `mysql_*`-functions are deprecated. The [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) says: "*This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.*". So PDO is simply an abstraction layer to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like other members have says, you should use PDO (with prepared statements) instead of mysql_.

One possible implementation:

HTML (form.php)

```
<select name="list1" id="list1">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="list2" id="list2"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#list1").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "get_list2.php?id=" + $(this).val(),                          
        type: 'GET',                   
        dataType:'json',                   
        success : function(data) {  
            if (data.success) {
                $('#list2').html(data.options);
            }
            else {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP (get_list2.php)

```
require_once("config.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (!isset($id) || !is_numeric($id))
    $reponse = array('success' => FALSE);
else {
    // Where $db is a instance of PDO

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = :id");
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $options = "";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $options .= '<option value="'. $row .'">'. $row .'</option>';
    }

    $response = array(
        'success' => TRUE,
        'options' => $options
    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

PS : not tested but it should works... I guess.

Comment: Thanks Guicara this will be a great help to me!

Comment: You're welcome ;) I have updated my post: the options (<option...) are now built by the PHP Script. It's more optimized  for client.